# Is this system in stable or unstable equilibrium?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law, equilibrium, stability

6 positive, identical charges $+q$ are placed in a hexagon. A negative charge whose value I want to determine is placed at the center to keep the system in equilibrium. Which means $dU/dr = 0$.

But is this system in stable or unstable equilibrium?

Comment: What will happen if you displace the negative charge by a small amount?

Comment: More mathematically: the first derivative tells you where the critical points are, but you need the second derivative to establish if locally the potential is stable or unstable.

Comment: @farcher I did think of that. However, I feel like it isn't in unstable equilibrium since the potential energy can always be increased by bringing these charges closer hence it is not at a Maxima at the equilibrium position.

Answer (score 0):

Other people hinted in their comments how one can analyze stability of the equilibrium, but there is also a general Earnshow's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) stating that a system of point charges cannot be in a stationary stable equilibrium if there are only electrostatic forces in the system.

Comment: not sure the charges on the hexagon are free to move...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Not sure they are not free to move:-)